# Please migrate off JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints - Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-cloud-endpoints, google-drive-android-api

Similar to other developers, I got an email from Google regarding my Android app, saying "Please migrate off JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints", and it lists the offending API as:

Google Drive API version drive@2 and "Global HTTP Batch Endpoint"

It says that I should somehow "migrate off" it, but is not clear how. I updated the dependency from:

google-api-services-drive:v2-rev305-1.23.0

to

google-api-services-drive:v2-rev332-1.25.0

But is this enough? Or must I upgrade to drive:v3, which is lacking some functionality from v2 and would be very difficult to use in my case? Or perform some other magic???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a blog for Google Developers about [discontinuing support for JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html).

The [JSON-RPC protocol](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) and Global HTTP Batch ([Javascript example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch)) features was based on an architecture using a single shared proxy to receive requests for all APIs. To improve performance and security, these features are no longer compatible with the latest architecture and business requirements.

> As a result, next year, on **March 25, 2019** we will discontinue support
>   for both these features.

You can check the guidance from the blog which will help you ease the transition and also consult the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/products/).

Comment: Thank you @jess. From this comment on blog I assume I should be fine after updating to the latest version of Google Drive API v2: "Google API Client Libraries have been regenerated to no longer make requests to the global HTTP batch endpoint. Clients using these libraries must upgrade to the latest version."

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps :)